# Error message received while trying to post a question: You can only post once every 40 minutes

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

While posting a question, I received an error message from the system:

> You can only post once every 40 minutes.

Here is a screenshot of my post and the error message:

---

[image]

---

However, I haven't asked any questions yet!!!!

Here is a screen shot of my user account to demonstrate that:

---

[image]

---

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thank you guys, I am able now to post a new question. Really I don't know why? but it's working fine now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no restrictions or rate limits on your account - it's just a Stack Exchange filter to prevent repetitive spam posts.

If you're using a shared IP address on a network, like at a school or work, it might get triggered by someone else there posting within a 40 minute time period. It might also get triggered if you post to more than one Stack Exchange site within a 40 minute time period too.

If you encounter this, just wait for 40 minutes to pass, or sign-in using a different network connection.

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: No problem! Maybe you'll get the same question on the site you moderate someday so can just pass it along there too :-)